# Undo after "Replace all"

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, undo, qtextedit

I have implemented a "replace all" function that gets triggered when the replace all button on the "Find and replace" window is pressed. 
However, if I try to undo the changes with the build-in undo function nothing happens.

Does it have something to do with my text editor not being focused when the dialog window shows?

```
def handle_replace_all():
    old = find_win.line_edit_find.text() # text to replace
    new = find_win.line_edit_replace.text() # new text

    cursor = self.text_edit.textCursor()
    cursor.beginEditBlock()

    current_text = self.text_edit.toPlainText()
    replaced_text = current_text.replace(old, new)
    self.text_edit.setPlainText(replaced_text)

    cursor.endEditBlock()


find_window.button_replace_all.clicked.connect(handle_replace_all)
```

Why is that happening? 
Appreciate any help.

Comment: [setPlainText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setPlainText) always clears the undo/redo history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the undo-redo functionality you must make the modifications using only the [`QTextCursor`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html):

```py
def handle_replace_all(self):
    old = find_win.line_edit_find.text() # text to replace
    new = find_win.line_edit_replace.text() # new text

    current_text = self.text_edit.toPlainText()
    replaced_text = current_text.replace(old, new)

    cursor = self.text_edit.textCursor()
    cursor.beginEditBlock()
    cursor.select(QtGui.QTextCursor.Document)
    cursor.removeSelectedText()
    cursor.insertText(replaced_text)
    cursor.endEditBlock()
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much.